# I need to write X to the power of Y in HTML ( Y is superscript of X )

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to write X to the power of Y in **HTML**
( **Y is superscript of X** ) .

> *Example-*
>
> X<sup>Y</sup>

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `<sup>` tag:

```html
X<sup>Y</sup>
```

If you want to use an index, use the `<sub>` tag:

```html
X<sub>Y</sub>
```

Comment: It helped a lot, and I will check the answer as accepted.